# Is it possible to have a custom footer on the PDF version of book?

Tags: gitbook

I'd like to include a small logo in the footer on every page on the PDF version of a book but not on the html version.

Is this possible? Any pointers on how I might achieve this?

I'm using git book version 2.0.1

Thanks a million.

ct

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to add a logo to the pdf and NOT to the html version.

I think one possibility to achieve this goal is to make a second html version. The first one is your gitbook, the second one is a copy of the first one, only with a logo at the end of each page. Then you can convert the second one to a pdf.

Another possibility would be to search for a watermark tool for pdf files and add the logo this way.

Sadly both ways are additional expenses, but I see no other way

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how to put a logo at the end of each page on the html version?

Nice idea on the watermark - I think I'll give that a shot.

Comment: One possibility would be to use a localtheme for the gitbook. I would not recommend that idea, because it's easy to run into errors.

Comment: Another possibility would be to write a script that would append a footer to each page